# Change url after a form submission without using a redirect

Tags: django

Following the submission of a registration form, I want the user to go to a thanks/confirmation page.

The registration form is at /register/ and the confirmation page is at /register/confirm/

I understand I can do this like:

```
if register_form.is_valid():
#save data etc.


#SCENARIO 1
#go to the confirmation view
return register_confirm(request)
```

This displays the confirmation page in the browser, but the actual URL does NOT change from /register/ to /register/confirm/.

```
#SCENARIO 2
#redirect to confirmation view
return redirect('register_confirm')
```

This displays the confirmation page in the browser and the actual URL DOES change from /register/ to /register/confirm/ (EDITED following @Borut comment)

```
#SCENARIO 3
#redirect to URL
return redirect('confirm/')
```

This displays the confirmation page in the browser and the actual URL DOES change from /register/ to /register/confirm/

So the scenarios in number 2 & 3 above does what I want in terms of the users being shown the confirmation page and the URL changing in the browser. (It's important to me that the URL changes in the browser for a few reasons, but not least because I want my analytics to record hits to the confirmation page).

**However, I really don't think any use of 'redirect' is correct in this scenario. I simply want to move the user to the confirmation page (to avoid accidental re-submission of the form if they press refresh). From my understanding, redirects give a 301 or 302 status code for example, implying that the page has been moved either temporarily or permanently.**

In the scenario of simply moving the user to a new page (i.e. linking without them having to actually click a link), the register and confirmation page should have a status code of 200. **I don't want search engines thinking I'm redirecting the /register/ URL for example with a 301 or 302 status code.**

Please can someone explain how to move the user to a new page, with the different URL showing in the browser window, but without using a redirect, or at least not giving a 30x status code.

Thank you!

Comment: So, search engine is supposed to register at your site and get confirmation page? Well, it won't. If you did redirect and URL did not change, then you're doing something wrong. In principle, when user registers, POST request is made at /register/ and if you redirect user after successful post, redirect is done with 302 status code and /register/confirm/ is rendered with GET request and 200 status code.

Comment: So if the redirect is done with a 302 status code, when the user submits the form, is that not like telling search engines that /register/ has been temporarily moved to /register/confirm/? Which is what I don't want. You're right - I understand search engines won't register at my site, but when the user submits the form, does the /register/ page not get assigned a 302 code?

Comment: When user browses to /register/, page with form will be loaded with 200 status (GET method). This is what the search engine will see. When user registers and is redirected after successful POST, server will instruct browser with 302 status code and redirect url to redirect to the provided url. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#the-view) is how code should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to use `redirect` at all you can call the registration view from the confirmation URL and render a different template.

You didn't reveal much of your code so here is a general example:

urls.py

```
from . import views

path("register/", views.your_register_view)
path("register/confirm/", views.your_register_view)
```

register_template.html

```
<form action="register/confirm/" action="post">
  <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def your_register_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #validate form data here
        return render(request, "confirm_template.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "register_template.html")
```

basically you call the same view from two different urls and render templates according to the request type(POST or GET.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and it's a good one, but I wouldn't want to hard-code the URL into the the form action from a DRY perspective, and also I want to handle all the form validation errors on the /register/ page before the user is sent to the confirmation page, so setting the form action to go directly to the confirmation page wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: Give your path a name argument and add {% url 'confirm_page_name %} to the form's action attribute. You aren't repeating yourself in the code and that way the url is not hard-coded. Also, the only validation you can do before calling another view is on the client side using javascript (Unless you use ajax to call another Django view of course.)